# Formula derivation for adiabatic process

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

> $\pu{1 mol}$ of an ideal gas at $\pu{400 K}$ and $\pu{10 atm}$ is allowed to expand adiabatically against $\pu{2 atm}$ external pressure. Find the final temperature of the gas if it is diatomic.

While looking for the solution of the problem above, I came across the formula for adiabatic compression in a reference book, and I was wondering how I could derive it:

> $$T_2 = T_ 1 \left(\frac {C_V + P_\text{ex}\frac{R}{P_1} } { C_V + R}  \right)$$

First I tried using the enthalpy equation
$$∆H = ∆W + ∆nRT,$$

but it proved to be futile. Then I tried using the definition of an adiabatic process, $PV^\gamma$, but that too didn't yield the desired result.
Could someone kindly help me solve this question?

Comment: Chem+Math Expression formatting reference:
 [MathJax Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) / [Chem+Math expressions/formulas/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) / [Upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) / [Math SE Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

Comment: For plain text formatting by StackExchange markdown, see as inspiration [SE meta - formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) // [SE meta -  tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support)  // [Advanced formatting](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/hidden-points-of-editing-you-probably-didnt-know)

Comment: The _definition_ of adiabatic process is _"no thermal exchange with environment"_ and not what you said. $PV^\gamma$ is derived from that. So you are not against memorizing formulae when they are nice. (Same with me.) Now to the point: what is $P_{ex}$?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I forgot to give the context in which the term P (ex) is used.

Comment: Imagine that you gave me a problem on calculating a potential energy of an apple. Now imagine that I come up with an answer that involves the mass of the apple, the gravity of Earth, the distance to the Moon, and the pressure at the bottom of the Mariana trench. Without looking at the actual expression, do you think it may be correct? Why or why not?

Comment: I apologise for the confusion, but I am as clueless as you are. I checked the solution for that question, and the author has directly used the above mentioned formula. My main goal is not just to prove the formula, but to arrive at the answer to the given problem.

Comment: @IvanNeretin, I do understand why you may feel that the formula is incorrect. However, I'm sure that the formula used is exactly correct. Here $P_{ex}$ is the final pressure after expansion.

Comment: What's $P_2$, then?

Comment: I'm extremely sorry, I should have noticed that before. For this question, $P_2$, as you said, is nothing but the final pressure after expansion, i.e., $P_{ex}$.

Comment: This is an _irreversible_ adiabatic change there is already an answer here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/97677/irreversible-adiabatic-process-against-constant-external-pressure

Comment: Thank you so much, @porphyrin!